# Specify NPM module platform to use in Angular

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, kendo-ui-angular2

I have an existing Angular app that works a charm in Chrome but fails on (obviously) Internet Explorer. What's happening is this:

Several of the NPM modules I install come with different distributions. So for example, the folder structure under `kendo-angular-charts` looks like this:

```
- dist
   |- cdn
   |- es
   |- es2015
   |- npm
   |- systemjs
```

When the site breaks in IE, it's because of the following declaration in `es2015\common\configuration.service.js`:

```
export class Change {
    constructor(key, value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

It breaks (invalid syntax error) because ES2015 classes are [not supported in Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class). But there is also a perfectly valid ES5 version of the file in the `es` folder.

So how do I use that instead?

I have checked `angular.json` and `package.json` for options that seem related, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to specify the JavaScript dialect to be used in your compiler **output**, is the `target` property in `tsconfig.json`. In our case we needed to set its value to `es5`.

This only applies to your code though, not to the imported packages.

Additionally, most imports normally just specify the package name, but you should also look for imports that specifically target the wrong version. In our case, we had an import under `@progress/kendo-angular-charts/dist/es2015`, which was the source of our problem.

Answer (score 0):

See the Angular browser support documentation (https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills) - there's no need to import different builds of specific packages. If you're using the Angular CLI, you can just edit the `src/polyfills.ts` file and uncomment the browser polyfills.

If you're not using the Angular CLI, you can import core-js using NPM and import the relevant polyfills (https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js).

Comment: I already have all the `core-js` polyfills uncommented, as well as `classlist.js`. More interestingly, why even distribute several versions of the module if only one will ever be used?

Answer (score 0):

was there ever an answer found to this.  I am having the same issue with the grid. It was working a couple of weeks ago and now it is not.  I cannot determine what changed to cause the use of the es2015 vs the es library. Is there a particular core-js polyfill that controls this?

Comment: The only solutions I found were to specify the `target` in `tsconfig.json` as `es5`. That seems to work for everything else. Also, check your imports to be sure you don't explicitly import an es2015 version of a package. We wound up removing the dependency that caused the issue.

Comment: Thanks Cobus, after reading your answer I dug through our recent changes and found where a dependency had been added that was an es2015 version.  That fixed it. Thanks for the reply.